# Open Default Browser Settings page programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to open the settings page of the default browser for Android 
programmatically from an application?

Through some intent? or 
Maybe some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use this code for call Browser settings page from our application

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE);
// It launches Chooser without specify the package name becz ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USUAGE  // action is used in Other apps also.
 i.setPackage("com.android.browser");
 startActivity(i);
```

Note: it supports from APi14 why this means that Settings page is not accessible from outside of Browser .From Api14 they provide intent-action for this.based on this action we can access it from outside

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a little extension to the question, is there any way to open the advanced settings intent?

Comment: Advance Settings is Fragment. so we cant call from outside. dont worry i will try alternate way.if i solve let u know.sorry for inconvenience

Comment: As I can see this option doesn't work on `api19+` is there any other option to open settings with default browser??