# To open settings page of chrome browser in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I am building an android application in which i need to open settings page of chrome browser.
I have researched a lot but didn't found any satisfactory result.I have used intent for default browser but that was not working in case of chrome browser.
Does anyone has any idea about this ?
thankyou in advance !

Comment: had you refered this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297492/open-default-browser-settings-page-programmatically

Comment: yes, it works for default browser of android.but for chrome it does not works after changing the package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not appear to export that activity, so it cannot be started by third-party apps.

Even if they did, that behavior could easily vary from version to version of Chrome for Android. Google does not document or support access to such activities from any of their commercial apps, let alone Chrome.