# Chrome custom tab crashes if chrome browser is disabled by the user in his device

Tags: android, pdf, browser, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to open `pdf file` in `chrome custom tab`, it works fine by using this code

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=" +pdflink));
```

But the problem is, if the user have disabled chrome from app settings and there is no other browser it crashes. So how can i open it in the chrome custom tab if it is disabled.

Thanks in advance.

this is the exception that is showing up in the logcat.

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://docs.google.com/... (has extras) }
```

Comment: which crash ???

Comment: i told it, if the user have disabled chrome browser and there is no other browser then this code makes the application crash.

Comment: Does that crash have any name ? like NullPointerException etc.

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: i answered to your post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

try {
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=" +pdflink));
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    // display message to user
}
```

Comment: i know how to handle a exception but what i wanted is to know that then how to open my pdf file in those custom tabs without chrome browser

Comment: @Anmol alternatively you can use WebView to open pdf file.

Comment: @Vishal Very helpful -Vote up! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Handle your exception like below

```
try{
   CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
   CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
   customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=" +pdflink));
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
   // Handle your exception
}
```

**EDIT**

If user has disabled it then you can ask user to enable it from **settings**.

Code for open phone settings

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

**REASON** behind this, can be easily searched from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059478/to-open-settings-page-of-chrome-browser-in-android-programmatically).
Written by **CommonsWare**

> Chrome does not appear to export that activity, so it cannot be started by third-party apps.
>
> Even if they did, that behavior could easily vary from version to version of Chrome for Android. Google does not document or support access to such activities from any of their commercial apps, let alone Chrome.

Comment: i know how to handle a exception but what i wanted is to know that then how to open my pdf file in those custom tabs without chrome browser

Comment: ok, but i am looking for some other alternative. Anyway thanks

Comment: i knew you are going to ask this , and i did a research and found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059478/to-open-settings-page-of-chrome-browser-in-android-programmatically) useful

Comment: that link points to, how to open chrome settings, but i cant ask user to open settings and enable a app just to open one page in my app. So i am finding some other alternative for it. BTW thanks for your efforts.